# How to generate Classification Analysis tables in R?

Tags: r, classification

So far I have done the discriminant analysis. I generated the posterior probabilities, structure loadings, and group centroids.

I have 1 grouping variable : history

I have 3 discriminant variables : mhpg, exercise, and control

here is the code so far

```
td <- read.delim("H:/Desktop/TAB DATA.txt")
td$history<-factor(td$history)
fit<-lda(history~mhpg+exercise+control, data=td)
git<-predict(fit)
xx<-subset(td, select=c(mhpg, control, exercise))
cor(xx,git$x)
aggregate(git$x~history,data=td,FUN=mean)
tst<-lm(cbind(mhpg,control,exercise)~history,data=td)
```

Basically, the above code is for discriminant analysis.

Now I want generate frequency classification and percent classification tables for classification analysis.

my attempted code (which i sampled from someone else to no avail) is:

```
td[6] <- git$class
td$V6<-factor(td$V6)
ftab<-table(td$history,dt$V6)
prop.table(ftab,1)
```

Where column 6 is my grouping variable history.

I get the following error when trying to make td$V6 a categorical variable with factor

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "V6", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 50
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I really don't know why the sample code used a capital V out of nowhere. Below is the data. Column 6 is the grouping variable, history. Column 5 is the discriminant variable, control. column 7 is the discriminant variable, exercise. Column 8 is the discriminant variable, mhpg.

```
1   3   6   0   2   0   4   2   4   3   0   6   0
1   4   5   0   0   1   2   5   4   6   1   4   1
1   4   4   0   2   1   1   8   6   7   1   2   1
2   4   9   0   2   1   0   6   7   8   1   4   1
2   4   3   1   4   1   2   6   6   6   1   4   1
2   5   7   0   1   1   3   6   7   7   1   1   1
2   5   8   0   1   1   1   6   6   7   1   5   1
2   6   7   0   1   1   0   9   8   8   1   3   1
2   6   4   1   2   1   2   5   7   6   1   5   1
3   4   10  0   1   1   1   8   5   7   1   4   1
3   4   4   0   1   1   1   8   9   8   1   3   1
3   4   7   0   1   0   1   6   3   4   0   8   0
3   5   4   1   4   1   2   5   4   5   0   5   1
3   5   7   0   2   1   1   7   5   7   1   4   1
3   5   6   0   0   1   0   10  9   10  1   3   1
3   5   6   0   2   1   1   9   10  9   1   2   1
3   5   5   1   2   1   2   5   4   4   0   9   1
3   6   2   1   4   1   3   6   4   4   0   7   1
3   6   3   1   2   1   2   7   5   5   0   6   1
3   6   5   1   2   1   2   6   7   6   1   6   1
3   6   7   1   3   1   3   5   4   4   0   8   1
3   6   5   1   2   1   2   5   3   3   0   10  1
3   7   8   0   0   1   1   7   6   7   1   5   1
3   7   5   1   2   1   1   5   5   5   0   6   1
3   7   6   1   2   0   4   3   1   2   0   9   0
3   8   6   1   2   1   1   6   5   5   0   7   1
3   8   9   0   0   1   0   7   5   6   1   3   1
4   5   5   1   2   1   1   5   6   5   0   6   1
4   5   5   1   2   0   2   3   3   4   0   8   0
4   6   8   0   0   1   2   8   7   7   1   4   1
4   6   6   1   3   1   2   5   4   4   0   7   0
4   6   5   1   3   1   2   4   3   2   0   8   0
4   7   2   0   3   0   4   3   6   6   1   4   1
4   7   4   1   3   0   3   4   2   1   0   7   0
4   7   7   1   3   0   4   4   5   5   0   7   0
4   7   6   1   3   0   3   3   6   5   0   4   0
5   7   5   1   1   0   4   1   7   4   0   7   1
5   8   1   1   3   0   3   4   8   7   1   5   0
5   8   3   1   3   0   3   4   5   6   1   5   1
5   9   4   1   4   0   3   2   7   5   0   5   1
5   9   6   1   4   0   3   4   6   6   1   7   0
5   10  4   1   3   0   3   4   2   3   0   6   0
1   1   8   0   1   0   2   5   6   5   0   6   1
1   2   7   0   1   1   1   7   8   9   1   5   0
1   2   7   0   1   1   0   7   5   6   1   5   1
1   3   5   0   1   1   2   7   8   8   1   5   0
2   3   3   1   2   1   2   6   7   6   1   6   0
2   3   6   1   1   1   2   7   6   4   0   7   0
2   4   6   1   3   1   3   6   5   5   0   6   0
2   5   4   1   3   1   3   4   4   3   0   6   0
```

Comment: What is `colnames(td)`? I imagine that `V6` is a column name in the dataset of the person whose code you have borrowed.

Comment: @dd3 Yes I wish i knew what the sample data looked like but I unfortunately do not. In any case, I still have provided to code for the discriminant analysis, and my question is asking for classification analysis tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tbl <- table(td$history,git$class)
tbl
#     0  1
#   0 13  2
#   1  1 34

prop.table(tbl)
#        0    1
#   0 0.26 0.04
#   1 0.02 0.68
```

These are the classification tables.

Regarding why your "borrowed" code does not run, there are too many possibilities.

First, if you import the data set you provided without column names, R will assign names `Vn` where n is 1,2,3, etc. But if this was the case none of your code would run as you refer to columns `history`, `control`, etc. So at least those must be named properly.

Second, in the line:

```
ftab<-table(td$history,dt$V6)
```

you refer to `dt$V6`. AFAICT there is no `dt` (is this a typo?).

Comment: yes, all the columns have to have a header, which I gave them separately in excel. dt was in fact a typo. But you have provided the correct code. Perhaps V9 referred to a grouping variable in a data set without headers and because git$class are the predicted groupings of the cases there was bound to be a mismatch in lengths when plotted as a table if the sample code referred to another data set while using git$class for this data set in particular.